# How to Enable Intel Visualization Technology(VT-X) without BIOS Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, bios, haxm

I am Developing android application using Eclipse. I got error HAX Kernal is not installed. I installed Intel HAXM using SDK manager. Even though the problem is occurred. Hiper-V is also disabled in my windows feature.

I forget my BIOS Password. So i am not tried using BIOS Setup. Please help me to enable Intel Visualization Technology(VT-X) without BIOS Setup

**I got Below Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Please help me to enable Intel Visualization Technology(VT-X) without BIOS Setup

That is not possible, sorry. Contact your PC manufacturer for assistance in getting into your BIOS setup.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and I had solved it by myself

Don,t worry here is the simple solution for you:

1. Go to your standalone SDK Manager, and find for Intel_HAXM type of package in Extras section. In worst case if it is already ind=stalled then try to update or reinstall it.
2. Select that package and then install it from the SDK Manager.
3. Now here is the important part, Go to "C:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" and then open "intelhaxm-android.exe" .
4. Install it. If it says that your computer already has this installed , do you want to update it, then go for the same.
5. Restart your Android Studio or eclipse, and now everything is fine.

Comment: When the OP did this work (over a year ago), your step #3 and 4 resulted in the error message shown in the question. Please explain, in detail, how your steps will get around the error message shown in the question.

Comment: It was just my experience, how I have solved myself. Please follow from step 1 to step 5, forgot about your past errors. Just try once